# 2006 Mitsubishi Lancer Ralliart, wont start, no crank but lights

Tags: starting, mitsubishi

Hi I have a 2006 ralliart, its a 5 speed and it wont start at all, no crank but theres lights and I can hear the fuel pump delivering fuel, I replaced the battery when I bought it as it was pretty much dead, then the starter made the grinding sound to indicate it was failing so i replaced it too but now it wont turn over at all no crank or anything, when i tried it for the first time it rolled over no problem, no ticking or knocking, it sounded fine, but now it wont start.

Comment: Have you rechecked your work? Did the S wire come off the solenoid? Is the clutch interlock switch working? Is the ignition switch passing power to the relay? Does the relay pass power to the S terminal on the solenoid?  Does the starter have power on the B+ wire? Is the Starter body grounded?